# Populating multiple java classes from 1 properties file with only get access

Tags: java, properties

I have 2 java Properties classes; 1st one has reference to 2nd one. Both have static fields and have only get methods for those fields.

This is the first one:

```
public class MyAppProperties {
   private static String COMPANY_NAME;
   private static ConnectionProperties CONNECTION_PROPERTIES;

   public static String getCompanyName() {
      return COMPANY_NAME;
   }
   public static ConnectionProperties getConnectionProperties() {
      return CONNECTION_PROPERTIES;
   }
}
```

This is the 2nd one:

```
public class ConnectionProperties {
   private static String DRIVER_NAME;                       
   private static String DATABASE_URL;                      
   private static String DATABASE_USERID;                   
   private static String DATABASE_PASSWORD;             

   public static String getDriverName() {
    return DRIVER_NAME;
   }
   public static String getDatabaseUrl() {
    return DATABASE_URL;
   }
   public static String getDatabaseUserId() {
    return DATABASE_USERID;
   }
   public static String getDatabasePassword() {
    return DATABASE_PASSWORD;
   }
}
```

All the property values are in 1 `.properties` file. My concern is how to populate the fields in each of those classes from that `.properties` file. I was thinking about using `static` initializer block. I was hoping to use `static` initializer block on MyAppProperties class to read from the `.properties` file and populate the fields of both MyAppProperties class and ConnectionProperties class. But I could not do it.

Is there any way to read from the `.properties` file and populate fields of both these classes? I don't want to define set methods of the fields in those classes.

Comment: If there are no set methods and the fields are private you can only refer to them from inside the class.  You'll have to put a static block in both classes and read your same one property file in each.

Comment: Usually if a properties java class is referenced in another properties java class then what is the standard way to populate it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean --- where are you referencing either properties java class from the other?